# QList with columns

Tags: list, pyqt, qlistview, qlistwidget

Does anyone know of an easy way to create a QlistView or QListWidget with columns?

All I need is a list with 2 columns that is undeitable and sortable.

Comment: Is there a reason that a QTableWidget with 2 columns wouldn't work?

Comment: Thechnically it would, but I would need a table that doesn't have any cell lines. I would need it to look like a list with just two columns.

Comment: You can set the `gridline-color` property in a style sheet to match the background color.  For example, `myTable.setStyleSheet('QTableWidget {gridline-color:white}')`.

Comment: I have ended up going with your approach, only difference is I use self.myTable.setShowGrid ( False ) to hide the grid. THank you for the suggestion